# How to use glClearBuffer* in Cocoa OpenGLView to clear color buffer

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, opengl

I'm trying to understand how to use glClearBuffer* to change the background color in a (either single or double buffered) NSOpenGLView in Cocoa for OS X.

The following code fragment as suggested by the OpenGL Superbible fails with GL_INVALID_OPERATION:

```
GLfloat red[] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, red);
```

What do I need to supply for the second parameter?

I'm using a double buffered View extending OpenGLView.

```
#import "MyOpenGLView.h"
#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>

@implementation MyOpenGLView


-(void) drawRect: (NSRect) bounds
{

    GLfloat red[] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, red);

    GLenum e = glGetError();

    // e == GL_INVALID_OPERATION after this call
    // and the view is drawn in black

    // The following two lines work as intended:
    //glClearColor(1.0, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    [[self openGLContext] flushBuffer];
}

@end
```

Comment: After some further digging, can you clarify whether you have a 3.2+ core context or not in your application? Maybe query the value of the `GL_VERSION` string. `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` can be generated if you make a call to a core profile function in a compatibility (2.1) context. OS X is unique among platforms in that the API functions are all statically linked, so you have access to 3.2 functions in a 2.1 profile context (you do not load the functions ***after*** creating the context); OS X handles this situation by emitting `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` and doing no actual work.

Comment: Yes, glGetString(GL_VERSION) reports v2.1: So what I need to do is change the context to v3.2. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really? It is giving you `GL_INVALID_OPEARATION`?

This function is not supposed to generate that error... are you sure something earlier in your program did not create the error and you are mistaking the source?

The bigger problem however, is that using `GL_COLOR` as the buffer in this API call expects the second parameter to be an index into your set of draw buffers. It is unclear how your draw buffers are setup in this code, it is possible that you have `GL_NONE`. As there is no defined error behavior if you try to clear a draw buffer when `GL_NONE` is used, I suppose an implementation might choose to raise `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`.

In order for your current usage of `glClearBufferfv (...)` to make sense, I would expect to see something like this:

```
GLenum  buffers [] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 };
GLfloat red     [] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

glDrawBuffers   (2, buffers);
glClearBufferfv (GL_COLOR, 0, red);
```

Now this call will clear `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`, if you wanted to clear `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1`, you could replace `0` with `1`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. glClearBufferfv indeed does give GL_INVALID_OPERATION, glGetError returns 0 just before the call to glClearBufferfv.

Comment: Ah, that is interesting. It is logical to assume that when your draw buffers are `GL_NONE` that an **Invalid Operation** would result. However, the official OpenGL specification does not define this behavior - I'll have to send the ARB a message about this.

Comment: After explicitly setting the view's core profile to NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core by changing NSOpenGLPixelFormat in awakeFromNib the code fragment above works as intended. Maybe you'd like to update your answer to include the compatibility issue.